# Unix Time stamp adding 2 weeks, 4 weeks, 6 weeks, 8 weeks

Tags: php

So I need to get the Unix time correct for my Ternary operator to work. What I am trying to do is to add 2,4,6,8 weeks to my Unix timestamp and echo out If its a 2 week time span it would be a P1 4 weeks it will be a P2 etc... My Unix Timestamp should be echoing out "Is a P4" but is not!

[image]

Comment: Please add the code to the question. Use some debugging to see what your values come out as, `var_dump()` would be useful. You also don't need the 3 additional values, just double, triple, and quadruple the 2 week value.

Comment: The `$mod` timestamp in your code is from september (in the past). The `$twoWeeks` - `$e1ghtWeeks` timestamps you're checking against are in the future. So `$mod` will never be `>=` any of those timestamps.

Comment: Thanks!!! All I need was to do was <= (less than or equal to) like you said not >=

Answer (score 0):

Look like that you use bad comparsion operator. In your example is `$mod` smaller than `$p4`.
You must use `$eightWeeks >= $mod` or `$mod <= $eightWeeks`

Edit:
Ofcourse in this case you must use another logic for distinguish between P1...P4.
For example use a Switch statement

```
switch (true) {
   case $mod <= $twoWeeks:
   echo "Is a P1";
   break;

   case $mod <= $fourWeeks:
   echo "Is a P2";
   break;
   // etc.....
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ill try to use a switch statement and see if that fix's my issue