# Ifelse unix timestamp

Tags: php

Ok here is my issue I tried to use a Ternary operator and a switch break on my issue and still coming up with the same results.

Now Iam trying an ifelse to see if this works but Iam still getting the same error where it should be echoing out "is a P4" but instead it's stating that 
this is a P1

```
<?php
//************************************
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180920/unix-time-stamp-adding-  2-weeks-4-weeks-6-weeks-8-weeks/53181428#53181428
//unix time stamp 
//************************************
//1536079080 = 04-09-2018 (Day of the task)
//1541376000 = 11-06-2018 (todays date )
//1542758400 = 11-21-2018 (2 weeks and 1)
//************************************
// > Greater than
// < Less than 
// >=   Greater than or equal to
// <=   Less than or equal to
//************************************

$mod = 1536079080; //unix time stamp 
$moDate = new DateTime('@'. $mod, new   DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); //Unix change to PST time 
$today = date("d/m/Y"); //todays date


$twoWeeks = time() + (3600*24*14);  //NOW + ( 3600 sec = 1 hour * 24       hours/day * 14 days)
$fourWeeks= time() + (3600*24*28);
$sixWeeks = time() + (3600*24*42);
$eightWeeks = time() + (3600*24*56);


// Less than or equal to and less than
$p1 = ($mod <= $twoWeeks && $mod < $fourWeeks)? true : false;
$res1 = ($p1) ? 'Is a P1' : 'Is not a P1'."<br>";

//Greater than or equal to and less then  6 weeks
$p2 = ($mod >= $fourWeeks && $mod < $sixWeeks)? true : false;
$res2 = ($p2) ? 'is a P2' : 'Is not a P2'."<br>";

//Greater than or equal to and less then 8 weeks
$p3 = ($mod >= $sixWeeks && $mod < $eightWeeks)? true : false;
$res3 = ($p3) ? 'Is a P3' : 'Is not a P3'."<br>";

// is equal to 8 weeks and greater then 8 weeks
$p4 = ($mod == $eightWeeks && $mode > $eightWeeks)? true : false;
$res4 = ($p4) ? 'Is a P4' : 'Is not a P4'."<br>";




echo $res1 , $res2, $res3, $res4;

//Output
//Is a P1
//Is not a P2
//Is not a P3
//Is not a P4

?>
```

Comment: You have a typo: in the $p4 check you are using $mode instead of $mod

Comment: I think one of your issues is that time() will include the current second & you're using $p4 = $mod == $eightWeeks; Unless you run your script down to the second it will never be true.

Comment: This does exactly what it says it will do, not what you want.  Please explain your requirements more fully.  Tuesday, September 4 2018 is always going to match "P1" ... Did you mean to use subtraction to look at "weeks AGO"?

Comment: Iam trying to add 2 weeks to a P1.. 4 weeks to a P2.. 6 weeks to a P3..8 weeks to a P$

Comment: and i just changed the mode to mod thanks for that

Comment: 1536079080 = 04-09-2018 (Day of the task) should be echoing out a P4 so i changed time() to $mod and still get the same error

Comment: $twoWeeks = $mod + (3600*24*14);  //NOW + ( 3600 sec = 1 hour * 24 hours/day * 14 days)
    $fourWeeks= $mod + (3600*24*28);
    $sixWeeks = $mod + (3600*24*42);
    $eightWeeks = $mod + (3600*24*56);

Comment: You're *never* changing $mod, and you're complaining that you keep getting the same result.... ?  If you want to assign, you use one "=" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel a bit like understanding and doing your home work ;-) but here is a feasible solution, I think...

```
$mod = 1546079080; //unix time stamp
$moDate = new DateTime('@'. $mod, new   DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); 
//Unix change to PST time
$today = date("d/m/Y"); //todays date
echo $mod . "<br>";

$twoWeeks = time() + (3600*24*14);  //NOW + ( 3600 sec = 1 hour * 24       hours/day * 14 days)
$fourWeeks= time() + (3600*24*28);
$sixWeeks = time() + (3600*24*42);
$eightWeeks = time() + (3600*24*56);


// Period 1 between 2 and 4 weeks from now
$p1 = ($mod == $twoWeeks && $mod < $fourWeeks)? true : false;
$res1 = ($p1 ? 'Is a P1' : 'Is not a P1')."<br>";

// Period 2 between 4 and 6 weeks from now
$p2 = ($mod >= $fourWeeks && $mod < $sixWeeks)? true : false;
$res2 = ($p2 ? 'is a P2' : 'Is not a P2')."<br>";

// Period 3 between 6 and 8 weeks from now
$p3 = ($mod >= $sixWeeks && $mod < $eightWeeks)? true : false;
$res3 = ($p3 ? 'Is a P3' : 'Is not a P3')."<br>";

// Period 4 more than 8 weeks in future
$p4 = ($mod >= $eightWeeks) ? true : false;
$res4 = ($p4 ? 'Is a P4' : 'Is not a P4')."<br>";

echo $twoWeeks .'<br>'. $fourWeeks .'<br>'.  $sixWeeks .'<br>'. $eightWeeks .'<br><br>' ;
echo $res1 , $res2, $res3, $res4;

// Output
// 1546079080
// 1543432972
// 1544642572
// 1545852172
// 1547061772
// 
// Is not a P1
// Is not a P2
// Is a P3
// Is not a P4
```

Comment: Thanks, Edwin! Your input is much appreciated! Even tho it doesn't seem like i didn't do my homework, I did but I think my understanding of how to get my result is probably wasn't there, but this helps me out a lot

Comment: I am new to having an account to Stack Overflow so I am assuming that by accepting the correct answer I just click on the check mark (indicating green)?

Comment: Also I had another questino instead of using the time() finction and I use my $mod variable then i would get the dates i need but to use that in the Ternary operator to spit out true or false how would i be able to get that work ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$mod = 1536079080; //unix time stamp
$moDate = new DateTime('@'. $mod, new   DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles')); 
//Unix change to PST time
$today = date("d/m/Y"); //todays date
echo $mod . "<br>";

$twoWeeks = $mod + (3600*24*14);  //NOW + ( 3600 sec = 1 hour * 24       hours/day  * 14 days)
$fourWeeks= $mod + (3600*24*28);
$sixWeeks = $mod + (3600*24*42);
$eightWeeks = $mod + (3600*24*56);


// Period 1 between 2 and 4 weeks from now
$p1 = ($mod == $twoWeeks && $mod < $fourWeeks)? true : false;
$res1 = ($p1 ? 'Is a P1' : 'Is not a P1')."<br>";

// Period 2 between 4 and 6 weeks from now
$p2 = ($mod >= $fourWeeks && $mod < $sixWeeks)? true : false;
$res2 = ($p2 ? 'is a P2' : 'Is not a P2')."<br>";

// Period 3 between 6 and 8 weeks from now
$p3 = ($mod >= $sixWeeks && $mod < $eightWeeks)? true : false;
$res3 = ($p3 ? 'Is a P3' : 'Is not a P3')."<br>";

// Period 4 more than 8 weeks in future
$p4 = ($mod >= $eightWeeks) ? true : false;
$res4 = ($p4 ? 'Is a P4' : 'Is not a P4')."<br>";

echo $twoWeeks .'<br>'. $fourWeeks .'<br>'.  $sixWeeks .'<br>'. $eightWeeks  .'<br><br>' ;
echo $res1 , $res2, $res3, $res4;
```

Comment: So the following listed above show I removed time() and added $mod

Comment: and that is now giving me the weeks i need for the unix time but I cant find out why the Ternary operator is not echoing out the right P(what ever its supposed to be)

Comment: 1536079080
    1537288680
    1538498280
    1539707880
1540917480

    Is not a P1
    Is not a P2
    Is not a P3
    Is not a P4